# Count frequencies of elements in array

Tags: c++

I've been writing code to get the frequencies of elements of an array. The code works, but it uses a lot of "old style" C constructs, some of which I feel should be changed to more C++-like features, but I don't know exactly which way would be best. In general, I feel that a lot of the code could be improved to be more elegant.

The first two functions, `remdups` and `freq`, are helper functions for `getFrequencies`, which is "facade" of the API.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

template <class T> void remdups(T *arr, size_t *n)
{
    for (size_t i = 1; i < *n; ) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i-1]) {
            memmove(arr + i - 1, arr + i, (*n-i) * sizeof (T));
            --*n;
        } else
            ++i;
    }
}

int *freq(const int *arr, size_t n, size_t *outN)
{
    int *freq = new int[n], cnt;

    for (size_t i = *outN = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        freq[i] = -1;
        cnt = 1;
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                ++cnt;
                freq[j] = 0;
            }
        }
        if (freq[i] != 0) {
            freq[i] = cnt;
            ++*outN;
        }
    }

    // remove duplicate frequency entries
    remdups<int>(freq, outN);
    return freq;
}

std::vector<std::pair<int, size_t>> getFrequencies(std::vector<int> arr)
{
    size_t n = arr.size(), newSize;
    int *freqs = freq(&arr[0], n, &newSize);

    // remove duplicate values from the array
    remdups(&arr[0], &newSize);

    std::vector<std::pair<int, size_t>> ret;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < newSize; ++i)
        ret.push_back(std::pair<int, size_t> { arr[i], freqs[i] });

    delete []freqs;
    return ret;
}
```

Example driver code:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 5, -3, -3, -3, -2, 0, 0 };
    auto freqs = getFrequencies(v);

    printf("%8s %8s\n", "Elem.", "Freq.");
    for (auto it = freqs.cbegin(); it != freqs.cend(); ++it)
        printf("%8d %8zu\n", it->first, it->second);
}
```

Comment: templates and std::vector are not part of C and will not compile in a strict C compiler. You might want to loose the old C I/O and use std::cin and std::cout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems over-complicated.  A simpler solution would use a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` for the counting:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::size_t> counts;
for (auto const &element: container) {
     ++counts[element];
}
```

---

Instead of being tied to `std::vector<int>`, we could make the code much more flexible as a template, taking a pair of iterators (or, from C++20, a `std::range`) with any appropriate element type.  The signature might look something like:

```
template<typename Iter>
auto getFrequencies(Iter begin, Iter end)
   -> std::unordered_map<decltype(*Iter), std::size_t>;
```

We might use constraints or SFINAE to choose whether to return an ordered or unordered map, based on whether `*Iter` is ordered and/or hashable.

Comment: `typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::difference_type`? That's what `std::count` returns. Also, should we give the user to specify the template arguments to `std::unordered_map` to enable usage with types for which something other than `std::equal_to` or `std::hash` has to be used?

Comment: Yep @L.F. makes sense.  Perhaps easiest if the user just specifies the entire type of the map.  Anyway, this answer was just a loose sketch to suggest a simpler approach, rather than a full worked example (more learning value that way, plus I'm busy IRL ATM).